# how to get value from json style value in php

Tags: php

{"items":["3","5"],"exclude_spu":null}

[image]

As you can see, value style is json.

how can I get ["3","5"] from json style in php?

Comment: You [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and access it

Comment: I have already tried with it, but I got error.

Comment: "status": false,
    "message": "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",
    "code": 500,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$jsonString = '{"items":["3","5"],"exclude_spu":null}';

$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$value = $jsonArray["items"];
```